# Combining multiple CSS animations into one overall animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a set of animations that I queue up one after the other to create a bigger overall animation. For the sake of simplicity, I've created a simple fiddle to demo what I mean, but it's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve (code on bottom)...

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/qgvrs/5/

What I want to do is combine all of these into one animation instead of several. Currently, I add a class to trigger the different stages of the animation, but what I would like to do is add a class **only once** to start the animation, and then it'll just go.

I don't see how to combine the animations into one since they work on different elements. I'm still fairly new to CSS3 animations, so is it possible to do this?

Any thoughts?

---

### The Code

HTML

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outside {
    border: 1px solid magenta;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.inside {
    border: 1px solid skyblue;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    margin-top: -31px;
    margin-left: -31px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scale-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.8);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.bounce {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
}

.animate {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

.click {
    border: 1px solid skyblue;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
}

.click .inside {
    border: 1px solid magenta;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
}

.clicked {
    border: 1px solid magenta;
}

.clicked .inside {
    border: 1px solid skyblue;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 750ms;
    -webkit-animation-name: scale-in;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function() {
        var jqElement = $('.outside');

        jqElement
          .off()
          .addClass('animate')
          .addClass('bounce');

        jqElement.on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd', function(event) {

          event.stopPropagation();

          jqElement
            .removeClass('bounce')
            .removeClass('animate')
            .off()
            .addClass('animate')
            .addClass('click');

          jqElement.on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd', function(event) {

            event.stopPropagation();

            jqElement
              .removeClass('click')
              .removeClass('animate')
              .off()
              .addClass('clicked');

            setTimeout(function() {
              jqElement.removeClass('clicked');
            }, 500);
          });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One animation one element is how it works as the animations change the styles of a single element. You can however apply delays to the animations to achieve what you want, allowing you to move pretty much everything out of JS.

This example merges your `.outside`  an `.inside` animations, by basically appending them with a comma to the rule and you JS now just adds the class like this `-webkit-animation-name: button-bounce, rotate, skyblue;`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sEKnC/3/)

### CSS

```
.outside.animate {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, .5s, .5s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms, 1000ms, 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-name: button-bounce, rotate, skyblue;
}

.animate {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

.outside.animate .inside {
    -webkit-animation-delay: .5s, .5s, 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms, 1000ms, 750ms;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate, magenta, scale-in;
}
```

#### New animations

```
@-webkit-keyframes magenta {
    0% { border: 1px solid magenta; }
    99.99% { border: 1px solid magenta; }
    100% { border: 1px solid skyblue; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes skyblue {
    0% { border: 1px solid skyblue; }
    99.99% { border: 1px solid skyblue; }
    100% { border: 1px solid magenta; }
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function() {
        var count = 0;
        var jqElement = $('.outside');
        if (!jqElement.hasClass('animate')) {
            jqElement.addClass('animate');
            jqElement.on('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd', function(event) {
                count++;
                if (count >= 6) {
                    jqElement.off('animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd');
                    jqElement.removeClass('animate');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hey Daniel, thanks for this! I did make an update to the code after I posted but it seems like you started on this before my update... I added a third animation at the end. Would you mind taking a look at my code again?

Comment: nice! thanks! now, let's see if I can apply this to my more complex animation :P

Comment: Daniel... there's a particular reason why I use multiple animations... to change the styling at the beginning of each. It seems like there's no way to do that with your current fiddle. Notice in the original fiddle how the border color changes from the beginning to the end. Is that possible to include with your approach?

Comment: @Hristo Updated with a fix for the border colours, I didn't notice before. Also hooked up animationend listening so you can trigger it more than once.

Answer (score 27):

You can use multiple animations separate by comma in shorthand property:

```
.selector
{
    animation: animation-name 2s infinite,
    other-animation-name 1s;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with webkit animation and two 3D rotates, from what I can see.

Comment: Try this: `-webkit-animation: animation-name 2s infinite,
    other-animation-name 1s;`

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work for the same type of animation e.g. rotation, etc... the 2nd overwrites the first.   Workaround I read about suggests wrapping the element in a div and applying one animation to the element, the other to the containing div.