# How can I apply multiple transform declarations to one element?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have an element with two classes, one called "rotate" that will rotate the element 360 degrees and another called "doublesize" that will scale the element 2x its normal size:

```css
.rotate {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.rotate:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.doublesize {
    transform: scale(1);
}

.doublesize:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sbw8W/

I'm guessing this does not work because the classes override each other's `transform` property?

I know that I could easily do this in one CSS rule like:

```css
.doublerotatesize {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}

.doublerotatesize:hover {
    transform: scale(2) rotate(360deg);
}
```

But I would like to be able to apply each class separately from the other if it is possible.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> I'm guessing this does not work because the classes override each other's `transform` property?

Correct. This is an unfortunate limitation as a side-effect of how the cascade works.

You will have to specify both functions in a single `transform` declaration. You could simply chain both class selectors together instead of creating a new class for a combined transform:

```css
.doublesize.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}

.doublesize.rotate:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotate(360deg);
}
```

... but as you can see, the issue lies in the `transform` property rather than in the selector.

---

This is expected to be rectified in Transforms level 2, where each transform has been promoted to [its own property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-2/#individual-transforms), which would allow you to combine transforms simply by declaring them separately as you would any other combination of CSS properties. This means you would be able to simply do this:

```css
/* Note that rotate: 0deg and scale: 1 are omitted
   as they're the initial values */

.rotate:hover {
    rotate: 360deg;
}

.doublesize:hover {
    scale: 2;
}
```

... and take advantage of the cascade rather than be hindered by it. No need for specialized class names or combined CSS rules.

Comment: i should have been able to specify translateY and translateX without one overiding another.

Comment: Even with transforms level 2, it would still not be possible to apply 2 of the same transform via 2 different classes, which is still sometimes necessary. For example, you may want to transform horizontally in 1 class, and vertically in another. If they broke this up 1 more level (`transformX`, `transformY`, etc.) that would probably be enough.

Comment: @trysis: You're right. It seems SVG transforms and the CSS cascade just don't go well together at all :(

Answer (score 21):

Using CSS variables you can have this separation. The idea is to chain as many transformation as you want inside the element using CSS variables then later you update each variable individually:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  transform:
    /* I prepared 3 placeholder so we can chain 3 transformation later */
    var(--t1,) /* we need "nothing" as fallbak*/
    var(--t2,) 
    var(--t3,);
}

.transitionease {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.transitionease:hover {
  transition: all 3s ease;
}

.rotate {
  --t1: rotate(0deg);
}

.rotate:hover {
  --t1: rotate(360deg);
}

.doublesize {
  --t2: scale(1);
}

.doublesize:hover {
  --t2: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="transitionease"></div>
<div class="transitionease doublesize rotate "></div>
<div class="transitionease doublesize"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can surely combine multiple animation, but not by combining CSS classes. See the first answer here : [combining multiple css animations into one overall animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708695/combining-multiple-css-animations-into-one-overall-animation)

The first part tells you how to combine animation with CSS with some parameters (delay, duration) :

```
.outside.animate {
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, .5s, .5s;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms, 1000ms, 1000ms;
   -webkit-animation-name: button-bounce, rotate, skyblue;
}
```

For sure, you firstly need to define your animations.

Comment: But those are animations, not transitions.

Comment: This topic is about combining transform properties, transitions are not really the problem here.

Comment: No, they are all three completely different concepts. Transforms are animatable, which means animations and transitions can both work with transforms, but an animation and a transition can't contain each other.

Comment: I know, but the topic is about combining multiple transform properties. Animations can do that.

Comment: I tried animations first and encountered the same problem with transitions that the classes override each other.

[http://jsfiddle.net/9Eq5k/](http://jsfiddle.net/9Eq5k/)


Also trying to get the transition out effect with animations it causes the default animation to fire on page load so would need jquery/javascript to add the class after the first mouseout.

Was hoping for a scriptless solution, but probably going to need to use javascript to edit the css to achieve what I want anyway.

Comment: The question is about transforms, not animations.

Comment: This answer the transformations are set in CSS animations. This is the cleanest way to combine transform properties.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this using just CSS, but if you don't mind using some jQuery you can attach this effect:

```js
var $elem = $('.cssDropPinImage');

$({deg: 0}).animate({deg: 360}, {
  duration: 600,
  step: function(now) {
    var scale = (2 * now / 360);
    $elem.css({
      transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg) scale(' + scale + ')'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/40" class="cssDropPinImage">
```

Comment: Yes! I was trying to find the jQuery way of doing multiple transforms and that works. As an alternative you can also make a class using the single line notation then using `on()` event delegation bind it to an event for the class

Answer (score 0):

The question hints at a scale and rotate animation on hover. Another pragmatic way of solving this, is by rearranging the elements in the HTML and applying the individual transforms to the parent and the child, only responding to the hover on the parent element.

That looks something like this:

```html
<div class="doublesize">
   <div class="rotate"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.doublesize {
   transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.rotate {
   width: 100px; 
   height: 100px;
   background-color: red;   
   transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.doublesize:hover {
   transform: scale(2);    
}

.doublesize:hover .rotate {
   transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n38csxy1/4/

I know this is quite a leap from the original setup, but I hope this perspective helps someone nevertheless.