# jQuery add inline style on top of previous inline style for filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-filters

I have an element that I want to add multiple inline filter styles on top of at different times.

The code I have now always resets the inline style so that whatever I set last is all that is there.

Here is an example snippet:

```js
$("div").css("-webkit-filter","grayscale(1)");
$("div").css("-webkit-filter","blur(5px)");
```

```css
.box{background:blue; width:100px; height:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

You can see that i'm setting grayscale first and at that time it turns black.  Then I set blur second, but it erases the grayscale filter and turns it back to blue then it blurs.

I want both grayscale and blur to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're overwriting the previous style since they both use the same property.  Try putting them together in the same statement like so:

```
$("div").css("-webkit-filter","blur(5px) grayscale(1)");
```

EDIT: If you need to apply them at different times, try this:

```
$("div").css("-webkit-filter","grayscale(1)");
$("div").css("-webkit-filter","blur(5px) grayscale(1)");
```

This will set the grayscale first and then preserve it by reapplying it with the blur effect as well

Comment: As noted, the filters will be applied at different times so doing them together is not an option.

Comment: @sjmartin updated my answer, should be what you need

Comment: it's not.  your second example is an exact copy of the first line.  you are still setting them together at the same time.

Comment: Yes, because if you want both of them applied, you have to chain them together, otherwise you'll overwrite anything that's set previously.  The first line set the grayscale wherever you want only that, then preserves that setting by reapplying it when the blur is added.  If you don't want to hardcode the strings, save which effects have already been applied somewhere and concat the strings when setting the next filter

Answer (score 0):

This will take the current css and append the new stuff.

```
var $div = $("div");

$div.css($div.css() + "-webkit-filter","blur(5px)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add both filters in one line, as you can see here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Jquery wants to overwrite the css if your setting the same property.

This question also addresses a similar problem, doesn't seem like a very clean solution though.

[Don't overwrite css properties, but add to them with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373180/dont-overwrite-css-properties-but-add-to-them-with-jquery)